# Elegantly mapping two objects based on id?

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

I have two tables/lists of objects, which are connected by an ID (in SQL terms, a foreign key). Is there some elegant way to perform a transformation on them so I end up with the "child objects" being referenced in a property in the "parent"?

Example:

```
Table1: Id, Name
Table2: Id, Name, ForeignId (referencing Table1.Id)
```

Expected result:

```
Table2Object.Table1Object containing the correct object form Table1
```

I know I can do it with first grouping the children by Id (purely for performance) and then going over the parents with a foreach, but that seems rather ... well ... unelegant to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relations with underscore? Interesting =)
You can use [`_.map()`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) & [`_.filter()`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) for this:

```js
var t = [
    {id: 1, Name: 't1'},
    {id: 2, Name: 't2'},
    {id: 3, Name: 't3'},
    {id: 4, Name: 't4'}
];
var f = [
    {id: 1, Name: 'f1', ForeignId:1},
    {id: 2, Name: 'f2', ForeignId:1},
    {id: 3, Name: 'f3', ForeignId:2},
    {id: 4, Name: 'f4', ForeignId:3}
];

var res = _.map(t, function(p){
    var j = _.filter(f, function(n){
        return p.id === n.ForeignId;
    });
    if(j && j.length) p.f = j;
    return p;
});
```

`Res` structure:
[image]

Comment: "Relations with underscore? Interesting =)"
well, if you don't want to serialize the exactly same object a thousand times (and also recognize it as the same object client-side)...